# ¿Por qué no se muestran los sprites en la ventana?

Tags: c++, poo, sfml

Programando un juego en SFML y c++, me he topado con problemas al mostrar un vector de "naves enemigas". El problema es que no aparecen a diferencia de la nave del jugador que si se ve y se puede controlar.

Este es el código:

**Enemy.h:**

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H

#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Enemy {
private:
  sf::Texture texture;
  sf::Sprite enemySprite;

  float enemySpeed;
  int maxY, maxX;
public:
  Enemy(int _maxY, int _maxX);
  void render(sf::RenderWindow *wnd);
  void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
  void reset(float speed);
};

#endif
```

**Enemy.cpp:**

```
#include <ctime>

Enemy::Enemy(int _maxY, int _maxX) {
  texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Bookmaster/03_World/Media/Textures/Raptor.png");
  enemySprite.setTexture(texture);
  enemySprite.rotate(180);

  maxY = _maxY;
  maxX = _maxX;
}

void Enemy::render(sf::RenderWindow *wnd){
wnd->draw(enemySprite);
}

void Enemy::reset(float speed){
  srand(time(NULL));
  int num = rand();

  enemySpeed = speed;

  enemySprite.setPosition(num%maxX, maxY);
}

void Enemy::update(sf::Time deltaTime){
  enemySprite.move(0.0f, enemySpeed * deltaTime.asSeconds());

  if (enemySprite.getPosition().y > 600){
    reset(enemySpeed);
  }
}
```

**Game.h:**

```
 class Game {
 private:
   sf::RenderWindow *mWindow;
   Aircraft aircraft;
   std::vector<Enemy> enemies;

   void reset();
 private:
   void proccesEvent();
   void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
   void render();
 public:
   Game();
   void run();
 };
```

**Game.cpp:**

```
Game::Game(){
  mWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "ventana SFML"); 

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    enemies.push_back(Enemy(800, 600));
  }
}

void Game::proccesEvent(){
  sf::Event event;

  while(mWindow->pollEvent(event)){
    if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
      mWindow->close();
    }
  }
}

void Game::reset(){
  for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
    enemies[i].reset(100.0f);
  }
}

void Game::update(sf::Time deltaTime){
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)){
    aircraft.Up();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)){
    aircraft.Down();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)){
    aircraft.Left();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)){
    aircraft.Right();
  }

  aircraft.update(deltaTime); 

  for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
    enemies[i].update(deltaTime);
  }
}

void Game::render(){
  mWindow->clear();
  aircraft.Render(mWindow);
  for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
    enemies[i].render(mWindow);
  }
  mWindow->display();
}

void Game::run(){
  sf::Clock clock;
  while(mWindow->isOpen()){
    sf::Time deltaTime = clock.restart();

    proccesEvent();
    reset();
    update(deltaTime);
    render();
  }
}
```

Como dato adicional, al quitar la función **reset** de la función **run** en **Game.cpp**, aparecen unos cuadrados blancos en la ventana en lugar de las texturas de las naves enemigas y una sola a la vez. Cuando lo que debería hacer es mostrar todas las naves al mismo tiempo.

Cuál es el problema y cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: ¿El salto de línea en la ruta de la textura es un error de copiado o está asi en verdad? Eso podría explicar que no salgan las texturas.

Comment: es solo un error de copiado en el codigo real esta bien escrito, incluso he chequeado si las texturas se cargan correctamente y tampoco es ese el problema

Comment: Un detalle que veo raro también (disculpa pero no puedo probar tu código puesto que ni tengo un taller con SMFL ni tengo las texturas) es que el vector está usando los objetos por valor. Esto implica que al añadir un elemento (`enemies.push_back(Enemy(800, 600));`) estás llamando implícitamente al constructor copia... y no se si los objetos de SMFL soportan esta operación correctamente... prueba a trabajar con un vector de punteros...

Comment: probe pasarle al constructor de Enemy las dimensiones de la ventana con la funcion **gesize()** para obtener el tamaño de la ventana de esta forma: `enemies.push_back(Enemy(mWindow->getsize().x, mWindow->getsize().y))`. A eso te referías? algo que creo que tiene que ver es la funcion **reset** en Game, porque al quitarla del codigo aparecen cuadrados blancos en vez de las texturas de las naves enemigas. @eferion

Comment: Me refiero a tener `std::vector<Enemy*> enemies; ` y lo que ello implica. La inicialización debería quedar así `enemies.push_back(new Enemy(800, 600));` y el render `enemies[i]->render(mWindow);`.

Comment: Lo que comentas de los cuadros blancos puede ser un síntoma de que no se están cargando correctamente las texturas

Comment: @eferion puede ser y es. Tal y como se ve [en el tutoial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-sprite.php) en el apartado "*The white square problem*".

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster publica entonces la respuesta que ya has dado con el motivo

Comment: @eferion he dado con un posible motivo (además de los problemas de diseño), pero no estoy seguro de que ese sea el problema... en vista del código presente hay muchos problemas solapados.

Comment: me podrias pasar algunas sugerencias para corregir los errores? @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: @facundorotger para eso tendré que publicar respuesta, mas no se si tengo la solución a tu problema.

Answer (score 4):

Tienes importantes fallos de diseño en tu código que afectarán negativamente al rendimiento y a la [huella de memoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_footprint) [image] de tu aplicación.

Te aconsejo echar un vistazo a la [documentación o tutoriales de SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-sprite.php) [image] para conocer con más detalle estos problemas, en concreto destacaría estos párrafos (traducción mía):

> #### [El problema del cuadrado blanco](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem) [image]
>
> Has cargado la textura sin problemas, construido el sprite correctamente y... lo único que ves en tu pantalla es un cuadrado blanco. ¿Qué ha pasado?
>
> Este es un error común. Cuando estableces la textura de un sprite, lo único que se hace internamente es almacenar un puntero a la instancia de esa textura. Así pues, si la textura es destruida o se mueve a otro lugar en la memoria, el sprite acaba conteniendo un puntero a textura no válido.
>
> Este problema ocurre al escribir este tipo de función:
>
> ```
> sf::Sprite loadSprite(std::string filename)
> {
>     sf::Texture texture;
>     texture.loadFromFile(filename);
>
>    return sf::Sprite(texture);
> } // error: la textura se destruye aqui
> ```
>
> Debes gestionar correctamente el ciclo de vida de tus texturas y asegurarte de que viven mientras sean usadas por cualquier sprite.

Esto podría dar explicación a tu problema de cuadrados blancos, pero por lo que veo en tu código tu textura vive tanto como tu sprite ya que ambos elementos son miembros de la clase `Enemy`, pero esto en realidad es otro problema:

> #### [La importancia de usar el menor número de texturas posible](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-sprite.php#the-importance-of-using-as-few-textures-as-posible)  [image]
>
> Usar el menor número de texturas posible es una buena estrategia, y la razón es simple: Cambiar la textura actual es una operación costosa en la tarjeta gráfica. Pintar varios sprites que usan la misma textura resultará en el mejor rendimiento.

---

Por lo que puedo ver, estás usando la misma textura para todos los `Enemy` cargada una vez por cada uno de ellos ¡un total de 5 veces! Esto no explica tu problema del cuadrado blanco pero es un problema de rendimiento; tal vez (esto es un tiro a ciegas) cambiando la estrategia que usas para emparejar texturas y sprites tu problema se solucione. Yo te aconsejo una [fábrica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) de enemigos:

```
class EnemyFactory {
    // Textura que usaran todos los enemigos
    sf::Texture texture;

public:
    EnemyFactory() {
         texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Bookmaster/03_World/Media/Textures/Raptor.png");
    }

    Enemy create(int _maxY, int _maxX) {
         return { _maxY, _maxX, texture };
    }
};

class Enemy {
    // No lo llames enemySprite, ya sabemos que pertenece a un Enemy.
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    // No lo llames enemySpeed, ya sabemos que pertenece a un Enemy.
    float speed;
    int maxY, maxX;
    // El constructor es privado para no poderlo construir libremente.
    // Recibimos la textura a usar desde fuera de Enemy.
    Enemy(int _maxY, int _maxX, sf::Texture &t) {
        sprite.setTexture(t);
    }
public:
    // Esto permite a la clase EnemyFactory acceder a los metodos privados
    // de Enemy, como por ejemplo su constructor.
    friend class EnemyFactory;

    void render(sf::RenderWindow *wnd);
    void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
    void reset(float speed);
};
```

De esta manera, suponiendo que en `Game` tienes un miembro `EnemyFactory` llamado `enemy` puedes hacer esto:

```
Game::Game(){
    mWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "ventana SFML"); 

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
      enemies.push_back(enemy.create(800, 600));
    }
}
```

Eso hará que todos los enemigos compartan la misma **única textura** la cuál estará viva durante todo el ciclo de vida de `Game`.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- **Cambia tu estrategia de pintado de elementos**: Ahora mismo cada `Enemy` recibe un puntero para pintarse a si mismo en una `RenderWindow`, lo ideal debería ser al revés, fíjate que la estrategia de SFML es que [`RenderWindow`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php) reciba los elementos a pintar no que los elementos a pintar reciban dónde pintarse; no vayas en contra de la librería que usas: sigue sus estrategias.
- **Sigue el [Principio de la Mínima Sorpresa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_la_M%C3%ADnima_Sorpresa)**: Es mucho más habitual ordenar las coordenadas como horizontal (x) y vertical (y) que al revés; de hecho ese es el orden que usa SFML (y el 99% de las aplicaciones que usan coordenadas). Así que cambia el orden de las coordenadas en tu clase `Enemy`, este principio también está relacionado con el anterior punto.
- **No tiene sentido que los `Enemy` almacenen sus rango de libertad**: Parece que das a entender que cada enemigo puede moverse en coordenadas diferentes, eso no es algo que la clase `Enemy` debiera decidir si no que la clase `Game`, como gestora del juego, debería encargarse de ello.

Comment: El problema de las texturas se arreglo con tu sugerencia de la fabrica de enemigos y he corregido los otros errores que me marcaste. Pero una cosa que no entiendo es, si tengo un vector de enemigos, 5 enemigos en este caso por que solo aparece uno? se me ocurrio la posibilidad de que estuvieran superpuestos uno encima del otro pero eso no debería suceder ya que les doy valores aleatorios en el eje x para aparecer.  @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: @facundorotger ¿podría ser que estuvieras pintando sólo un enemigo?

Comment: pero si en la función **render** de game recorro todo el vector de enemigos y llamo a `enemies[i].render()` por cada miembro del vector. por que se estaría pintando solo uno? @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: @facundorotger sin ver nada del código nuevo que estás usando, simplemente puedo hacer conjeturas o consultar mi bola de cristal binaria.

Comment: @facundorotger podría suceder que todos los enemigos estén ubicados en el mismo punto... quizás no estás usando bien el generador de números aleatorios. De primeras ya te aviso que el generador solo hay que inicializarlo una vez... no una por cada uso. Tal y como lo inicializas y lo usas lo más seguro es que el generador aplique la misma semilla para todos los enemigos.