# ¿Cómo hacer que mi nave dispare?

Tags: c++, poo, sfml

Estoy tratando de aprender sobre programación de vídeojuegos, para eso estoy usando *la librería SFML2*. La idea es desarrollar un juego de naves y disparos.

La cuestión es que quiero hacer que la nave del jugador dispare.

Hasta ahora tengo el siguiente código:

Clase **Aircraft.h**:

```
class Aircraft {
  private:
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite mPlayer;

    float playerSpeed;
    sf::Vector2f playerDirection;
  public:
    Aircraft();
    void Render(sf::RenderWindow *wnd);
    void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
    sf::Vector2f getDirection(){
      return playerDirection;
    }

    void Up();
    void Down();
    void Left();
    void Right();
}
```

**Aircraft.cpp**:

```
Aircraft::Aircraft() {
  texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Book-master/02_Resources/Media/Textures/Eagle.png");
  mPlayer.setTexture(texture);
  mPlayer.setPosition(200.0f, 200.0f);

  playerDirection.x = 0.0f;
  playerDirection.y = 0.0f;
  playerSpeed = 220.0f;
}

void Aircraft::Render(sf::RenderWindow *wnd){
  wnd->draw(mPlayer);
}

void Aircraft::update(sf::Time dt){
  mPlayer.move(playerDirection * playerSpeed * dt.asSeconds());

  playerDirection.x = 0.0f;
  playerDirection.y = 0.0f;
}

void Aircraft::Up(){
  playerDirection.y = -1;
}

void Aircraft::Down(){
  playerDirection.y = 1;
}

void Aircraft::Left(){
  playerDirection.x = -1;
}

void Aircraft::Right(){
  playerDirection.x = 1;
}
```

Clase **Bullet.h** para los disparos:

```
class Bullet {
  private:
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

    float speed = -300.0f;

    int posX, posY;

  public:
    Bullet(int _posX, int _posY);
    void update(sf::Time deltaTime, int _posX, int _posY);
    void render(sf::RenderWindow *_wnd);
};
```

**Bullet.cpp**:

```
Bullet::Bullet(int _posX, int _posY) {
  texture.loadFromFile("SFML-Game-Development-Book-master/10_Network/Media/Textures/misil1.png");
  sprite.setTexture(texture);
  sprite.rotate(-90);
  sprite.setScale(0.5f, 0.5f);

  posX = _posX;
  posY = _posY;
}

void Bullet::update(sf::Time deltaTime, int _posX, int _posY){
  posX = _posX;
  posY = _posY;

  sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);

  sprite.move(0, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());
}

void Bullet::render(sf::RenderWindow *_wnd){
  _wnd->draw(sprite);
}
```

La clase **Game.h**:

```
class Game {
  private:
    sf::RenderWindow *mWindow;

    ScrollingBackground background;

    Aircraft aircraft;
    std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
    EnemyFactory enemy;
    Bullet bullet;

  private:
    void proccesEvent();
    void update(sf::Time deltaTime);
    void render();
    public:
    Game();
    void run();
};
```

**Game.cpp**:

```
Game::Game():bullet(0,0){
  mWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(640,480), "ventana SFML"); 

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    enemies.push_back(enemy.create(640,480));
  }
}

void Game::proccesEvent(){
  sf::Event event;

  while(mWindow->pollEvent(event)){
    if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
      mWindow->close();
    }
  }
}

void Game::update(sf::Time deltaTime){
  background.update(deltaTime);

  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)){
    aircraft.Up();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)){
    aircraft.Down();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)){
    aircraft.Left();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)){
    aircraft.Right();
  }
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)){
    bullet.update(deltaTime, aircraft.getDirection().x, aircraft.getDirection().y);
  }

  aircraft.update(deltaTime);

  for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
    enemies[i].update(deltaTime);
  }
}

void Game::render(){
  mWindow->clear();
  background.render(mWindow);
  aircraft.Render(mWindow);
  for (int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++){
    enemies[i].render(mWindow);
  }
  bullet.render(mWindow);
  mWindow->display();
}

void Game::run(){
  sf::Clock clock;
  while(mWindow->isOpen()){
    sf::Time deltaTime = clock.restart();
    proccesEvent();
    update(deltaTime);
    render();
  }
}
```

La idea es que al apretar la barra se cree la bala en la posición de la nave y se mueva solo verticalmente. El problema es que la bala no aparece en ningún momento. Las texturas, se cargan correctamente así que no creo que esté ahí el error.

Comment: Hola ! Tienes un `main` ? Hay un buen tutorial sobre el problema logico (y no grafico de ninguna manera) sobre openclassroom.com

Comment: Tienes la fabrica de enemigos y la colección de enemigos repetidos en la clase `Game`.

Comment: @facundorotger esta bien que edite su pregunta, pero pienso que tiene que tener encuenta si los cambios pueden afectar a las respuestas que ha obtenido, y si estos nuevos cambios estan generando otra pregunta creo que es mejor que realize otra pregunta, aqui un ejemplo uste pregunta inicialmente ->  **¿Cómo hacer que mi nave dispare?** ...

Comment: ...aunque realmente tendria a decir por que mi nave no dispara pues en su codigo se veia que lo esta intentado pero tampoco es cuestion de ser tan estrictos, pero este nuevo cambio -> **¿Por que no aparecen las naves enemigas?** es otra pegunta diferente, con lo que si alguin tiene un error similar las respuestas no son o puden no ser la acertadas, pienso que deberia de copiar esta pregunta como la tiene ahora y hacer una nueva pregunta, despues hacer un rollback de esta pregunta a como estaba anteriormente, si no sabe como hacerlo puede avisarme a mi o a otra persona que si sepa.Saludos

Comment: @facundorotger  La idea es ir creando una pregunta por poblema o problemas, pero dentro  pero publicados al mismo tiempo, si le surge con el tiempo otro problema diferente al primero, lo ideal es crear otra pregunta, y si este nuevo problema esta muy relacionado con la anterior pregunta poner un link en la nueva pregunta. Porque aunque la pregunta se suya quizas en un futuro pueda ser util para otro usuario con el mismo problema, ...

Comment: ... y si esta la pregunta con respuesta aparentemente sin sentido con respecto al ultimo texto de su pregunta, el usuario perderia tiempo en leer respustas que podrian ser la solucion a la pregunta antes de modificarlas, con lo que esto se empezaria a parecer a un foro.Saludos

Comment: disculpa escribí mal el código cuando hice la pregunta, ya esta corregido, no era esa la razón del problema @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: @facundorotger Si escribes una pregunta sobre un tema, después la modificas para que trate de otro tema y después la vuelves a modificar indicando que el segundo tema no tenía el problema que indicas, acabarás por liarme a mi y a todos los lectores del sitio. **POR FAVOR** devuelve la pregunta a su tema original (balística) y escribe una pregunta sobre tu problema real, yo ya me he perdido: no se ni lo que preguntas ni lo que necesitas ni si puedo ayudarte.

Comment: veo que cambio el titulo "acorde" con la pregunta inicial, voy hacer un rollback pues he visto que publico una pregunta nueva update esta en la revicion 5. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Tienes importantes fallos de diseño en tu código que afectarán negativamente al rendimiento y a la [huella de memoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_footprint) [image] de tu aplicación.

Te aconsejo echar un vistazo a la [documentación o tutoriales de SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-sprite.php) [image] para conocer con más detalle estos problemas, y leer de nuevo la [otra pregunta relacionada con SFML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63530/2742) que formulaste hace unos días.

---

Para empezar, llama la atención que en tu juego sólo exista un proyectil; si este proyectil está compartido entre el jugador y los enemigos tu juego va a ser muy aburrido (normalmente estos juegos tienen [muchos más proyectiles](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoot_%27em_up#Evoluci.C3.B3n_hacia_los_.C2.ABbullet_hell.C2.BB_y_llamamiento_al_culto)). Así que elimina el proyectil como miembro de la clase `Game`, no tiene ningún sentido que esté ahí.

La [balística](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bal%C3%ADstica) es un tema complicado en desarrollo de videojuegos, existen muchas soluciones y aproximaciones al problema. En tu caso no tienes nada que se parezca a una solución; te aconsejo que apliques los siguientes cambios:

- **Un *almacén* de proyectiles**: Con dos listas separadas de proyectiles, una para proyectiles amigos (proyectiles que no colisionan con el jugador pero colisionan con enemigos) y otra para proyectiles enemigos (proyectiles que colisionan con el jugador pero no con enemigos).
- **El proyectil debe moverse mediante un vector**: La velocidad de los proyectiles no debe ser un [escalar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalar_(matem%C3%A1tica)) si no un [vector](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector), con el vector puedes definir una dirección y una velocidad de movimiento.
- **El juego debe tener un apartado de balística**: Seguramente el mejor lugar para gestionar la balística sea en la función `void Game::update(sf::Time);`
- **Te falta el concepto de cadencia**: Ahora mismo disparas al presionar una tecla, lo que te daría una [cadencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadencia_de_tiro) ligada a tu [velocidad de refresco](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Im%C3%A1genes_por_segundo) lo que haría que tu nave parezca una manguera en lugar del honorable defensor del universo que debería ser.

---

La implementación la dejo a tu libre albedrío pero para gestionar la balística deberás realizar lo siguiente:

1. Al crear un proyectil, añadirlo a la lista adecuada.
2. Comprobar cada proyectil de la lista contra cada elemento contra el que pueda colisionar.
3. Por cada proyectil colisionado, aplicar la acción relacionada con la colisión (quitar vida o eliminar el enemigo o al jugador) y eliminar el proyectil (si procede) de la lista.
4. Por cada proyectil restante en cada lista avanzar en dirección al vector de movimiento.
5. Eliminar silenciosamente los proyectiles que tras avanzar, hayan salido de la zona de juego.

---

Insisto en que releas [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63306/por-qu%c3%a9-no-se-muestran-los-sprites-en-la-ventana/63530#63530) en tu otra pregunta pues **no has corregido tus problemas anteriores**. Tampoco estaría de más que eliminaras [tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63776/2742) que es en realidad otra pregunta.

Comment: Podrias darme un ejemplo de una implementacion apropiada para las balas de acuerdo a lo que yo hice? @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: La verdad es que no puedo @facundorotger ya que tal y como he dicho en tu código "*no tienes nada que se parezca a una solución*". Intenta implementar los puntos que he comentado.

Comment: @facundorotger ¿no crees que para pedir respuestas detalladas de la implementación, no convendría ser más específico en la pregunta aclarando lo que estás intentando y mostrando detalles minuciosos sobre los problemas que se te están presentando en la implementación, de modo que las respuestas puedan enfocarse sobre ese fragmento en específico? La idea del sitio es obtener respuestas de expertos a tus preguntas, pero algo que se debe considerar es que la especificidad de las respuestas depende siempre de la calidad de las preguntas, y no esperar una solución mágica al publicar todo tu código.

Comment: Cambie algunas cosas del código pero ahora tengo el problema de que no aparecen las naves enemigas en la ventana. A que se debe este problema y como puedo solucionarlo @PaperBirdMaster ?

Answer (score 2):

No sé de SMFL, pero según veo usted esta creando la bala aquí:

```
Game::Game():bullet(0,0){
```

Posiblemente la clase se esté creando sin erres pues si no, no podría usar
`void Game::render(){` con lo que no se le vería nada y estaría haciendo otro tipo de pregunta, así que dando por sentado lo anterior, usted crea la bala en la posición *0,0*.

Ahora en esta parte:

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)){
    bullet.update(deltaTime, aircraft.getDirection().x, aircraft.getDirection().y);
}
```

Usted actualiza la bala pero esto solo ocurre cuando pulsa la tecla, es posible que esto sea tan rápido que no lo vea (pero si usted está llamando a `bullet.render(mWindow);` y esta tiene una posición correcta quizás se le vería aunque fuera sin desplazarse).

*¿El uso de `aircraft.getDirection().x` es correcto?* No puede "o es su caso devuelve lo mismo" por ejemplo que algo así `aircraft.getPosition().x` que es el punto en el que se encuentra la aeronave en ese momento. y ajustarlo con + n para que la bala se sitúe en el punto con respecto a la aeronave que desee, pues como se vera mas abajo el desplazamiento quizás tenga que hacerlo de otra manera

Pero aun viéndose, pero en el siguiente *frame* o varias veces por *frame*, cuando se llame a `update(sf::Time deltaTime)` ya no se esta pulsando la tecla con lo que la bala no se desplazaría, pues tampoco se estaría llamando al *update* de `bullet`,

Quizás puede hacer algún cambio algo así:

---

```
//se podría prescindir del deltaTime en este método pero por no cambiar mucho su código, solo téngalo en cuenta pues es posible que no lo necesite 
void Bullet::posicionar_bullet(sf::Time deltaTime, int _posX, int _posY){
posX = _posX;
posY = _posY;

sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);

//sprite.move(0, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());
}

void Bullet::update(sf::Time deltaTime){

//sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);

sprite.move(0, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());
}
```

---

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)){
    bullet.posicionar_bullet(deltaTime, aircraft.getDirection().x, aircraft.getDirection().y);
}

aircraft.update(deltaTime);
bullet.update(deltaTime); //usamos el update de bullet para que sea llamado en cada update de juego
```

o

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)){
    bullet.posicionar_bullet(deltaTime, aircraft.getPosition().x, aircraft.getPosition().y);
}

aircraft.update(deltaTime);
bullet.update(deltaTime); //usamos el update de bullet para que sea llamado en cada update de juego
```

---

> Nota: como nota cada vez que se pulse la tecla la bala se reasignara
>   quizás tenga que comprobar cada cuanto se pude dispara etc o crear un
>   array de balas o mejor un pool de estas, pero solo se lo comento, pues
>   no es el caso de la pregunta
>
> ```
> if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)){
>     bullet.posicionar_bullet(deltaTime, aircraft.getDirection().x, aircraft.getDirection().y); 
> }
> ```

---

**UPDATE:**

Tiene los términos un poco extraños aun así pruebe estos cambios a ver que tal:

**`Aircraft.h`** añada:

```
sf::Vector2f getPosition();
```

**`Aircraft.cpp`** añada:

```
void sf::Vector2 Aircraft::getPosition(){
    return mPlayer.getPosition();
}
```

Y use esta parte en el update:

```
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)){
    bullet.posicionar_bullet(deltaTime, aircraft.getPosition().x, aircraft.getPosition().y);
}

aircraft.update(deltaTime);
bullet.update(deltaTime); //usamos el update de bullet para que sea llamado en cada update de juego
```

Y esta en bullet:

```
//se podría prescindir del delta time en este método pero por no cambiar mucho su código, solo téngalo en cuenta pues es posible que no lo necesite 
void Bullet::posicionar_bullet(sf::Time deltaTime, int _posX, int _posY){
posX = _posX;
posY = _posY;

sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);

//sprite.move(0, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());
}

void Bullet::update(sf::Time deltaTime){

//sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);

sprite.move(0, speed * deltaTime.asSeconds());
}
```

---

Comment: probe tu implementacion y tampoco funciono, tal vez esta fallando la funcion aircraft.getposition() como dijiste. Voy a agregar la clase Aircraft a la pregunta para que puedan verla @Angel Angel

Comment: @facundorotger le deje un update al final de la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: con eso se soluciono el problema. hay algunos detalles como que al apretar de nuevo la barra la bala se reinicia y vuelve a aparecer en la posición de la nave, pero eso se podría solucionar usando un vector de balas no? @Angel Angel

Comment: @facundorotger me alegra que lo solucionar, por un lado puede mirar esto y proceder como crea [tour] ya que comenta que lo soluciono.

Comment: @facundorotger Pero sobre lo que comenta, *...al apretar de nuevo la barra la bala se reinicia ...* ya se lo habia comentado incluso antes de solucionar su error, y la respues es si mas o menos, puede buscar por internet algun ejemplo sobre como implementar un pool de objetos, y aplicarlo para las balas, basicamente es un array u otra estructura similar con cierta cantidad de objetos en este caso del tipo Bullet ya creadas (sin asignar la posicion de estas o si es asignada que este fuera de la vista de la camara) y cuando quieras usar una nueva bala la coges desde el pool, el pool en si...

Comment: ... mismo tiene un mecanismo para recuperar las balas, lo vera al buscar alguna sobre ello, haciendo uso del pool se mejora el performace del juego. Si usa un array simple tendria que crear las balas cada vez que se quiera una, y añadirlas al array y despues crear un for que itere por los elementos de ese array y haga el update de la bala, pero tendria que eliminarlas por ejemplo comprobando que cuando estas salgan de la pantalla se eliminen de array, y asi todo el rato con lo que estas todo el tiempo creando objetos, en pool es + o - = pero sin tener que crear objetos todo el tiempo.Saludos